# Unable to pass date values in CSV file and failed to read in Selenium

Tags: java, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to read data from csv file. I have entered dates with formatted cells with mm/dd/yyyy. I saved it, after opening the date cells are like #####. When I am trying to read data from my code, it is unable to read. My code for csv file reading is like below,

```
public static List readTestCases(String filename, Class bean) {
    CsvToBeanMapper beanReader = new CsvToBeanMapper();
    List Testcases;
    Testcases = new ArrayList();
    Testcases = (List) beanReader.getBeanFromCsv("src/test/resources/testcases/" + filename + ".csv", bean);
    return Testcases;
}
```

EDIT:

I have testcase like this,

```
@Test(description="New Project")
    public void addSoftwareDefault(AddProjectBean projectBean)
    {
        softwareName="AutoSoftware11816";
        projectName="AutoProject17538";
        assertEquals(true,loginpage.gotoSignPage());
        assertEquals(true, loginpage.logintoPortal(PropertyMap.getInstance().getName(),PropertyMap.getInstance().getPassword(), "myToday"));
        assertEquals(true,addProject(projectBean)
    }
```

As the data cannot be read from csv, selenium is skipping this test...

The data is like this when I open in text editor

```
ProjectID,ProjectName,SoftwareName,ProjectDescription,ProjectTags,ProjectStartDate,ProjectFeatureCompletionDate,ProjectProductionReadyDate,ProjectSeverity
,,,,,,,,
AutoProject,AutoProject1224,AutoSoftware23345,This is Sample,Java,12/30/2015,1/30/2016,2/28/2016,High
```

Note: I am intentionally reading data from the second line after heading... first line is for description which I didn't filled...

Comment: Cells in Excel show as ##### when the data is too long for the column width. I suggest you either, widen the column in Excel, revealing the data, or open in a text editor.

Comment: I have widen the column and saved it... but same problem.... I will try in text editor...

Comment: Excel doesn't save column widths in csv files. Given that you saved it, I assume the data was visible when the column was widened?

Comment: Yeah... visible when widened....

Comment: OK, so the data is in the CSV file. What problem are you seeing with Java? The snipped included in your post has nothing to do with date parsing within the document itself.

Comment: Yeah, it just reads the data as it is. How can I read, I will try to edit in text editor...

Comment: When I tried in text editor, the dates are clearly showing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99308/discussion-between-dave-and-lokesh-s).